# Elisp extend variable lifetime

Tags: variables, emacs, lexical-scope

I have a loop in which I create a local variable during each iteration. I then declare a lambda that uses the local variable sometime in the future.

```
      (dolist (entry (read-lines "~/.emacs-projects"))
         (let ((project (car (json-read-from-string entry)))) ;; <---- I NEED THIS ONE
             (widget-create 'link
                     :button-prefix ""
                     :button-suffix ""
                     :action (lambda (wid &rest ignore) (load-project project)) ;; HERE
                     (format "%s : %s\n" (car project) (cdr project)))))
```

In the code above I create `project` and when `:action` triggers I want to use `project` as an argument to another function. Currently i am getting `Symbol’s value as variable is void: project` when the lambda is run which makes me think that the outer scope is not preserved.

How can I extend the lifetime of `project` so that I can access it in the lambda?

Comment: You're looking for a *closure* (or some analog thereof).  This is a common question for elisp over the years, so searching with that term will garner results (n.b. some of which will pre-date the availability of lexical-binding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the lexically scoped flavor of Emacs Lisp, which was one of the main novelties added to Emacs-24.  To do it, just add the following somewhere (usually inside a comment) on the first line of your Elisp file:

```
-*- lexical-binding:t -*-
```

Hopefully, at some point in the future, the old dynamically-scoped dialect will not be the default any more.

Answer (score 2):

Either use lexical scoping (non-`nil` [variable `lexical-binding`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html)) or use a list lambda form with the value of `project` substituted for the variable itself:

```lisp
 (dolist (entry (read-lines "~/.emacs-projects"))
         (let ((project (car (json-read-from-string entry)))) ;; <---- I NEED THIS ONE
             (widget-create 'link
                     :button-prefix ""
                     :button-suffix ""
                     :action `(lambda (wid &rest ignore) (load-project ',project)) ;; HERE
                     (format "%s : %s\n" (car project) (cdr project)))))
```

If your action function does not really need `project` *as a variable*, but it just needs its value, then you can just substitute the value, as shown.

But in that case your lambda form will be a list (whose car is `lambda`, etc.), so it will not be recognized as a function before it is evaluated. In particular, the byte compiler will see it only as a list, not as a function.